# Install Python Packages on Red Hat Linux 8.2 using PIP not working

Tags: python, apache, flask, pip, redhat

Working in a Corporate environment which has proxy server and thus i am setting proxy details  as advised in various forum. Software version details below

- OS - Red Hat 8.2
- Python Version - 3.6.8
- PIP Version - pip 9.0.3

Tried setting up environment variable

```
export http_proxy=http://servername:port
export https_proxy=https://servername:port
```

Tried using trustedhost setting. Executing below command inside python virtual environment

```
pip install --proxy=<http://servername:port \
    --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host pypi.org \
    --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org  Flask
```

Above command gives below Error

```
Collecting Flask
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Flask
```

If i remove trustedhost setting i get certification error

```
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:897)'),)': /simple/flask/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/flask/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate:
    HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): 
        Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/flask/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:897)'),)) - skipping
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda hard to reproduce, unfortunately, but at first glance, pypi repositories are going to be reached via HTTPS (I assume), not sure why you are explicitly specifying the schema for proxy:

```
pip install --proxy=<http://servername:port \
    --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host pypi.org \
    --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org  Flask
```

Shouldn't it actually be:

```
pip install --proxy=https://servername:port \
    --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host pypi.org \
    --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org  Flask
```

Alternatively, you could install the packages directly from sources (download them via wget - it's easier to set proxy there, I guess).

Comment: i have tried https as well. It does not work. Yes i can try downloading elsewhere and then reference but wondering how can i make PIP install work on Redhat.